How to decline meeting invitation in Outlook using .ics by automation test script in Dart/Flutter
I do integration automated testing. My task is get meeting invitation from Outlook and decline it, which will appear in the integrated messenger. My problem in the final stage, the Outlook not recognized modified .ics file for declining meeting invitation.
I have written code which was doing the following:

I receive .ics file of the meeting invitation through IMAP
I modify the .ics file: METHOD, STATUS ...
Through SMTP I send back modified .ics file to the respective email as attachment.

I have used enough_mail (used also 7bit->base64: not worked)
The modified ics file passed the iCalendar validation.
As a result, Outlook does not recognize modified file as .ics and processes it as ordinary attachment, and not declined the invitation.
When I send back original .ics mentioned in the step 1, Outlook recognized as proper .ics.
I think the problem is the modifying the METHOD in ics, when I am changing only that, Outlook does not recognize it as .ics.
What could be a problem?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
